# What are some words to describe "spat/fight" of different levels of seriousness and intensity?

Tags: grammar, american-english, vocabulary, british-english

Looking for words to describe:

1. Argument of very mild nature over who gets the front seat in a car.
2. Trump and arnold twitter spat.( i think spat would be correct here if I am not wrong)
3. Mild argument b/w husband and wife.
4. Very intense and serious fight between husband and wife.

Feel free to correct/rephrase my question if need be.

Comment: What did a thesaurus suggest and why weren't they any good?

Comment: thesaurus would just give me synonyms for word "fight".  Eg: battle, clash, combat, conflict, contest, dustup, fracas, fray, hassle, scrap, scrimmage, scrum, scuffle, skirmish, struggle. 
It does not rank words based on seriousness and intensity.

Comment: I see what you want but it is too broad as stated. You're asking for single words for a whole bunch of different situations and that just doesn't work well on a Q&A site (any single such question is bad enough). You probably want to reword the question to be to give the words you're interested in and ask what is their relative seriousness and or intensity.

Comment: You may have to use a dictionary to find the definitions of the synonyms and make your own list...

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are multiple ways to elucidate the type of argument depending on the parties involved, place of occurrence, intensity, the length of argument, whether it's verbal or written and so on. I think the following should address the context you provided.

1. Contretemps / tiff
2. Spat / afters / falling-out
3. Dissension
4. Squabble / row

Comment: Isnt  squabble used for matters that are trivial as opposed to serious?